# DLL export and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, dll, export

I'm trying to export a class and its base class from a DLL like this:

```
#ifdef MY_EXPORTS
    #define DECLSPEC_TEST __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DECLSPEC_TEST __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


class DECLSPEC_TEST BaseClass
{
  // stuff.
};

class DECLSPEC_TEST DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
  // This class only has a constructor which initializes the class differently.

};
```

But I try to use this class in another DLL, I keep getting an error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
"__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall DerivedClass::DerivedClass(void)"
 (__imp_??0DerivedClass@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function 
"public: __thiscall SomeOtherClass::SomeOtherClass(void)" (??0SomeOtherClass@@QAE@XZ)
```

I also looked at my exporting DLL with PE Explorer and I can't see the derived class in the exports list.

When I try to use the base class in my other DLL it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never heard of a class being a symbol.  I thought symbols were usually only variables or functions.  Why not quote the entire, exact error message here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I don't know how to explain this but I put the implementation of the derived class' constructor in a CPP file instead of within the class definition and the error went away...
thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 3):

there are two ways to load the DLL. The first is to reference one or more symbols from the DLL (your classname, for example), supply an appropriate import .LIB and let the linker figure everything out.

The second is to explicitly load the DLL via LoadLibrary.

Either approach works fine for C-level function exports. You can either let the linker handle it or call GetProcAddress as you noted.

But when it comes to exported classes, typically only the first approach is used, i.e., implicitly link to the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

The linker is complaining that it can't find the constructor for DerivedClass.  Try explicitly declaring it, defining it, and exporting it from your DLL:

Header file for DLL:

```
class DECLSPEC_TEST BaseClass
{
};

class DECLSPEC_TEST DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass();
};
```

Source cpp file for DLL:

```
DECLSPEC_TEST DerivedClass::DerivedClass() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you compiled your DLL, you also got a .lib file. This is your import library. You will need to link to it in order to connect to link-time dependencies like these.

Comment: @Idov: Your error seems to be evidence to the contrary; you may want to verify that you're linking to the right library (not an earlier compile of it). Either that, or you somehow didn't compile `DerivedClass` into your DLL. Can you post a single set of files (one .h/.cpp for the DLL, one .h/.cpp for the executable) that reproduces the problem? Something that we can actually build?

Comment: This is so weird...  I've just added an "include" statement to another unrelated CPP file in the project just to see what happens and suddenly the error was gone. Isn't it supposed to be built automatically when I sign it as a DLL export?

Comment: @Idov: Yes it should. But it may have been that the build for the executable didn't see that the import library wasn't rebuilt. Possibly it was a date/time issue. I've had glitches like that happen before.

Comment: So how can I solve this? I tried cleaning the solution or deleting the "debug" directory but it didn't help. :/

Comment: It seems that C++ name mangling causes name mismatches for declspec differences.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to check:

1. Ensure you are linking with the EXACT .LIB file you are producing from DLL project. It happens, by mistake that we build both projects but LIB file in target project is obsolete.
2. Ensure that associated CPP files, in DLL project, gets compiled.Using `__declspec` attribute on all methods is **not** required, since you are exporting entire class.
3. Using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com), ensure that DLL is actually having class and all its methods exported.
4. Ensure that there is no 64-bit/32-bit mismatch among .LIB files in both projects

Answer (score 0):

The only missing thing here that I see is a semicolon `;` after the class declarations. Other than that, the export should work fine.

One more thing to check: Did you declare the constructor in the derived class to be `public`?

Comment: Yes, the constructor is public. :/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in your `DerivedClass` you have declared a non-default constructor (i.e., different from `DerivedClass::DerivedClass()`).

In such cases the compiler will not produce a default constructor for you, so you have to define one, since it seems that for some reason you are using the default constructor of your `DerivedClass` (possibly in the implementation of DerivedClass, not necessarily in the code that uses the DLL).

It is not necessary that the default constructor be declared in the DLL interface, but it should be there.

If you are not willing to have a default constructor, a trick is the following:

declare a default constructor in the `private` part of DerivedClass definition.

In this way, any attempt to use it will produce a compiler error (instead of a linker error), so that you know where you are trying to use the default constructor and can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

according to my understanding I guess SomeOtherClass is trying to call the constructor of your BaseClass(), which in turn is calling the constructor of your DerivedClass(), but since SomeOtherClass does not have the definition of Derived class, so it is giving an error,

Probable solution could be to include your SomeOtherClass in that DervideClass.