# Export parent and base class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, dll, visual-studio-2017, export

Im trying to create a DLL consisting of C++ classes including inheritance. The DLL is supposed to be accessed by some console application.

Parent class:

paramCalculator.h

```
#ifdef MY_EXPORTS
#define PARAMCALCULATOR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PARAMCALCULATOR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


class PARAMCALCULATOR paramCalculator
{
public:
    paramCalculator();
    ~paramCalculator();

    float m_current;
};
```

paramCalculator.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

paramCalculator::paramCalculator()
{
}

paramCalculator::~paramCalculator()
{
}
```

Child class:

currentCalculator.h

```
#ifdef MY_EXPORTS
#define PARAMCALCULATOR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PARAMCALCULATOR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class PARAMCALCULATOR currentCalculator :
    public paramCalculator
{
public:
    currentCalculator();
    ~currentCalculator();

    float m_tubePower = 1500;
    float m_tubeCurrent;

    void calcCurrent(float vo);
};
```

currentCalculator.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

currentCalculator::currentCalculator()
{
}


currentCalculator::~currentCalculator()
{
}

void currentCalculator::calcCurrent(float vo)
{
    m_tubeCurrent = m_tubePower / vo;
    std::cout << m_tubeCurrent << std::endl;
    m_current = m_tubeCurrent;
}
```

The console application accessing the DLL looks as follows:

```
#include "paramCalculator.h"
#include "currentCalculator.h"

class tubeCurrent
{
public:
    tubeCurrent() {};
    ~tubeCurrent() {};

    void setParam(float v)
    {
        ab.calcCurrent(v);
        m_current = ab.m_tubeCurrent;
    }

    currentCalculator ab;
    float m_current;
};

int main()

{
    tubeCurrent ac;
    float voltage = 200;
    ac.setParam(voltage);
}
```

When running the console application it shows "7.5" on the output window, which is the expected calculated value for the current. This tells me that accessing the DLL works. However, the variables m_tubeCurrent and m_current have not been changed to value 7.5. Can anyone tell me how to fix this and get both variables to update its values?

During some tests i've found out that as soon as I remove the inheritance relation between both classes, the member variable "m_tubeCurrent" are updated successfully. However, im struggling to find a way to access the member variables when inheritance between both classes is involved.

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633471/dll-export-and-inheritance-in-c/6633559) question but couldn't solve my issue.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

In order to make myself more clear, here's two images of the debug window within the console application.

Inheritance is included and the calculated values are not assigned to the corresponding variables:

[image: Inheritance is included and the calculated values are not assigned to the corresponding variables]

No inheritance resulting in the calculated values being assigned to the corresponding variables:

[image: No inheritance resulting in the calculated values being assigned to the corresponding variables]

In the latter one, I have only changed the currentCalculator class definition within the currentCalculator.h file from

```
class PARAMCALCULATOR currentCalculator :
    public paramCalculator:
```

to

```
class PARAMCALCULATOR currentCalculator
```

Both variants calculate the values in the right manner when the DLL is executed, however only the latter one allows me to still access the variables after the DLL has been executed.

Comment: Did you try debuging your application?

Comment: If the output is correct, why do you think the variables are not updated?

Comment: I've edited my question to make myself more clear.

Comment: Have you exported the derived class? It seems that the variable is not initialized in the first case.

Comment: From my understanding the derived class is exported in the code snippets above. In both cases the variables are initialized, otherwise there would not be a correct console output of "7.5". Though, the variables seem to be somewhat uninitialized for the case including inheritance as soon as the DLL's work is done.

Comment: I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've just made a request over there. Can't upvote you since im not having enough points, might do so as soon as im allowed to though.

Comment: For anyone interested: Turned out that in my console application I still had a path to another DLL (which didn't have the inheritance relation) under Build Events -> Post-Build Event -> Command Line. Previously, I've tested the console application on another DLL's and obviously forgot to remove its path.